# A probability problem involving the Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: probability-distributions, fibonacci-numbers

I came across this problem from [Maths Mind 7](https://m.facebook.com/105511084358733/photos/a.106639180912590/207868390789668/?type=3&_rdr)
There is a frog jumping up over the stairs. The probability for it to jump 1 step is (1-p) and 2 steps is p. If the nth stair is broken, what is the chance for the frog to fall down?

I have learned the typical staircase problem is of the Fibonacci sequence, but how do I integrate it into a probability model? Would the Bernoulli distribution work in this case?

Comment: My first try, which might easily fail, would be recursion.  I would try to compute exact answers, based on each value of $n \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  Then, I would try to find a pattern in the data, try to form a hypothesis of the probability with respect to $(n)$ in general, and then try to prove the hypothesis.  As your question is presented, mathSE reviewers are liable to react negatively to it.  If you are interested in reversing this reaction, you can see [this mathSE article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful tips, I have improved my question a little bit, but I am really stuck on this question...

Comment: If you re-read the article that I linked to, you will see that there is much information that is missing from your question; hopefully, you will edit your question to add this  information: What is your math background, and what training / math tools are available to you that might be pertinent? For example, were there any previously solved problems, worked examples, or theorems that you have been exposed to, that might be pertinent here?  If so, what are they?  Also, have you had any involvement with recursion problems? ...see next comment

Comment: If you can not think of any other approach, then I suggest that you edit your question to show the details involved in the attempt that I suggested.  That is, compute each value for $n \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, examine the data, look for a pattern, try to form a hypothesis, and then try to prove the hypothesis.

Comment: For what it's worth, I personally disfavor the mathSE protocol as overly stringent in a situation like this, but there isn't anything that I can do about it.

Comment: Thank you @user2661923, I will give it a try ^_^